# Getting client IP from Ruby script through xinetd

Tags: ruby, sockets, stdin, inetd

How can I get the client IP Address from inside a Ruby script that is launched by xinetd through a stream socket?
In PHP I would just use `stream_socket_get_name(STDIN, true);`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After searching a lot for the solution, and even trying to ask on the #ruby channel on Freenode and being completely ignored, I've finally found the solution:

```
def to_ip(addr)
  (4...8).map{|x|addr[x]}.join('.')
end

socket = Socket.for_fd(STDIN.fileno)
ip = to_ip(socket.getpeername)
```

Hope this helps someone!